# The Great Arqade Meetup! - Part 1

Tags: discussion, meetup

**Update - August 8, 2012**
I'll be beginning Part 2 in the next few days.  Remember, if you're interested, make sure to put your location on the map.  The more we have, the better we can plan our locations.

**Preface**

On Friday (July 27), I threw out the idea of arranging a meetup for us Arqadians (bad pun, I know).  Based on the response I received, most everyone is in favor of doing this.

To make the planning a bit easier (and so we don't overload a single meta discussion with everything), I'm going to try to break down the planning bits into several parts.

**Part 1** - Decide how to do our meetup.  Several little ones, or one big one?
[**Part 2**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/the-great-arqade-meetup-part-2) - Where?
[**Part 3**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/the-great-arqade-meetup-part-3) - When, and how long?
**Part 4** - Activities
**Part 5** - Hosting Arrangements
**Part 6** - Travel Arrangements

If we do decide to do this, I'll happily take the brunt of the framework planning.  If we agree to have a meetup in Winnipeg, Canada, I'll even take on the planning for that.  The main point is, this is fun to talk about, but let's stop talking about it, and **do it**.

---

### Part 1

I'm starting the discussion on planning the particulars of trying to get us contentious lot into the same (general) physical space.  There are a couple options available to us on how we want to go about this:

1. StackOverflow tends to distribute the meetups around the globe, and have them in the same general date range, for the "Together in spirit" thing.  This would allow smaller, quicker meetings that don't require as much planning, as it would basically be a day long event, and that's it.
2. Buck the SO trend, and get all us crazy people together in the same space.  This one would require lots of planning, and would be a major time investment.  Would need to be planned out months in advance to ensure everything is in order, and everyone's made arrangements for work, pets, and whatnot.

Now, first things first: **StackExchange cannot cover travel expenses**.  We're on our own to get to wherever it is we're going.  I discussed this with [Lauren in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5566787#5566787), and while they can help us out with some stuff, like food and drinks, they can't help us get to where we're going.

Part of this decision is going to have to take into account where everyone lives.  To that end, I've created a [map](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699) we can use to locate ourselves.  We'll use this in Part 2 as well to figure out where to have our meetup(s).

---

## Map Instructions

It's not terribly obvious how to add a pin to the map. If you want to tag yourself:

1. Go to the [map](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699).
2. Click the giant red `EDIT` button. (note: Make sure you are signed into Google, otherwise this will not show up)
3. Right click the location where you want your pin to add it.
4. Make sure you put your **username** as the name of the pin.
5. Click 'done'.

With that in mind, here's the first decision we have to make.  How are we going to do this?  Or, do we even want to do this at all?

Comment: If we were to have them all at the same time, some webcams between the events would be cool. Although time zones would make it difficult.

Comment: Google doc of where interested users are located?

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's going to be in Part 2; I first want to see how we want to go about this, or even if there's enough interest to go part this.

Comment: I think where people are (and where they're willing to go to) is *kinda a big deal* when trying to determine how many and how large an affair to orchestrate.

Comment: I worry that "One big meetup" would be too difficult for everyone wanting to participate. We're pretty spread out, and trans-Atlantic flights are pretty expensive.

Comment: Hmm.  True.  If we decide to have one big meeting, and it turns out to be in Europe, I'd probably have to decline.  Alright, fair enough.  I'll edit it and create a map for us to pin ourselves.

Comment: Is the map supposed to let me select a location, and display the location of other users...? If so, it doesn't seem to be working/.

Comment: Ok, it'll work now.  It'll just start on Winnipeg, because that's where I live.

Comment: Over 9000 up-votes

Comment: I think someone did a google maps mashup that pinned users based on the location field in their profile, but I can't find it ATM.  I have a sneaking suspicion that it used a data dump as the source.

Comment: @MBraedley The idea is for users who are interested in doing this to pin their own locations.  We'll gauge interest and glean location data at the same time!

Comment: Basically no matter what I won't be attending because either A) It'll be one single event in America, which is too expensive for me, or B) It'll be multiple events but there's not enough Australians to meet up (I mean, there's probably like 2-3 of us, which isn't really worth it).

Comment: it might be better if your meetup coincided with an event such as PAX or PAX east, making it more likely people will show up

Comment: Upvote for Winnipeg!

Comment: am i the only guy here that lives in South Africa... Makes my kinda disappointed in my country's gaming community...

Comment: I'm feeling *really stupid* right now since I can't figure out how to add a damned pin for myself, so if someone wants to throw one near Dallas, TX for me ("Rilgon Arcsinh"), that'd be super neato. :D

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I added instructions for using the map. Give it a try yourself.

Comment: @StrixVaria Aha, that's what I was doing wrong, I was avoiding the big red button cause I didn't wanna break anything!

Comment: There was a [Stack Overflow Meetup Everywhere](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) a few months back. The link gives some tips for planning, might be helpful.

Comment: As a suggestion for a meet-up spot, FunSpot in Laconia, NH has the largest arcade int he world and is home to the American Classic Arcade Museum. It may be out of the way for most people but seems like an ideal spot given the theme. http://www.funspotnh.com/ (FYI, I am not affiliated with FunSpot in any way other than them taking my money for an afternoon of gaming)

Comment: I'm still trying to work out what the pun was

Comment: @MrSmooth while us Australians are few and far between, would you consider travelling to an SE Asia/Oceanic meetup?

Answer (score 13):

I think it's best if we have multiple meets-up, divided by location. Our users are spread all over the world, so I don't think having one central meet-up is realistic.

Stack Overflow uses a [meet-up](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/) website for scheduling it's meet-ups, so could do the same once the plans for this are further along.

Comment: you do realize that we may not have critical mass here in NS for a decent meet-up, right?

Comment: @MBraedley: the idea would be to have multiple central meet-ups in locations others could get to. i.e. having one Canadian meet-up in Toronto, and another in Vancouver.

Comment: I probably live closer to Toronto than you Nova Scotians.

Comment: @StrixVaria See you in Toronto! ;)

Comment: Yay, Toronto! :D

Comment: All you Europeans can just come to London. I'd suggest a meetup date post-Olympalopalyspe though.

Comment: @QAdley I think if we plan a meet-up it won't be for at *least* a month. If people are going to need to travel then they will need time to make plans.

Comment: @Wipqozn Although it'll be less of a big deal, there's the para-Olympalopalyse to consider too.

Comment: Europeans can travel to London and Canadians should travel to London, ON. London squared! :)

Comment: I'm more up for FAE's location, the netherlands ftw? :p

Comment: Unless there's a meetup in the NL, I'm pretty much 99% sure I won't be able to make whatever we're doing anyway due to travel costs, as I have to travel to the US in December and need to save my money for that. :/

Answer (score 0):

We should have one central meetup rather than trying to spread it out by location.

EDIT: I only put this answer in so there'd be something to represent each side of the discussion. I am personally against this idea, but it won't let me downvote my own posts.

Comment: This is actually the way I want it to work, logistics be damned.  So, upvoted!

Comment: @fbueckert No matter how badly you want this one, it will be difficult. We have several prominent users in Europe (badp, FAE, Ronan, etc.), as well as some in Singapore (YiJiang, I believe?). A single, central meetup could potentially cost a single person over $1,000 in travel expenses alone.

Comment: @Fluttershy Plus the time required for a meet-up. When people have work and school it's not easy to set time aside to travel half-way across the world.

Comment: @Fluttershy Singapore, yes. Of course, realistically I won't be able to attend either way - there simply isn't enough users nearby to have a meet up even if you don't go this way.