# The Great Arqade Meetup - Part 2

Tags: discussion, meetup

**Meetup Index**

[**Part 1**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5186/the-great-arqade-meetup-part-1) - Decide how to do our meetup.  Several little ones, or one big one?
[**Part 2**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/the-great-arqade-meetup-part-3) - Where?
**Part 3** - When, and how long?
**Part 4** - Activities
**Part 5** - Hosting Arrangements
**Part 6** - Travel Arrangements

[Google map for pinning your location.](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699)

---

**Map Instructions**

It's not terribly obvious how to add a pin to the map. If you want to tag yourself:

1. Go to the [map](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699).
2. Click the giant red `EDIT` button. (note: Make sure you are signed into Google, otherwise this will not show up)
3. Right click the location where you want your pin to add it.
4. Make sure you put your **username** as the name of the pin.
5. Click 'done'.

---

### Part 2

Part 1 has concluded with the choice to hold several little meetups rather than a single unified location.  As such, it's time to choose the locations of our meetups.  To a degree, when is going to bleed into location choices, as we may want to have our meetup as part of a larger event (such as PAX or such).

**Basic things to keep track of**

1. If you suggest a location that's your hometown, chances are quite good that if your location is chosen, you're going to be relied on to volunteer for helping to plan that meetup.  Keep that in mind.  It will cost you less monetarily, but probably more of your time.
2. If your suggestion has a date component, make note of that, and why.
3. Personally, I'd recommend keeping meetups outside of large cities, to try to lower total living expenses such as food and lodging.  That gets thrown out the window for other events, though.
4. **Upvote the location you want to go to.**
5. If you haven't pinned yourself on the [map](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=213689790075558322917.0004c60f50fcc5f857c9d&msa=0&ll=49.862776,-96.9104&spn=1.581051,4.22699) yet, don't forget to do that!  It helps track interest, as well as your location!

With that said, bring on the suggestions!

Comment: Well I'm the only person within a good thousand miles of me, so I guess I will just drink excessively and call it a meet-up! :D

Comment: What he ^ said. Nobody else is in germany? Sad face.

Comment: Gamescon perhaps? Valve is bringing HL3!

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to sit out of this entirely, seeing as the "where" depends entirely on the "when" of this for me. :(

Answer (score 7):

### Philadelphia

I don't have any skin in this game, but looking at the map and trying to maximize the number of people within 250km/150mi of a large urban center<sup>1</sup>, Philadelphia looks like a good fit for North America, with 5 people (Toronto and New York come in second with 4 people each). Heck, any urban center in Pennsylvania is relatively close for the majority of people in North America.

Given  what it entails to cross international borders (passports and whatnot) and that there's roughly double the number of people in the US as there are in Canada, it's probably better to favor an American city, too.

<sup>Note 1: you had specified a preference for not being in a large city, but given how spread out the North American community is, it's probably going to have to happen, as cities provide access to transportation (don't need to rent cars, can fly directly there) and other amenities (so one doesn't need to make the meetup the only focus of the trip).</sup>

Comment: I have to vote for this, if only because it's on my way to work.

Comment: I have an aversion to Philadelphia on account of having someone threaten to pistol whip me on my last visit.

Comment: @StrixVaria You should just avoid those kind of establishments in future then.

Comment: @StrixVaria That's why I like Philadelphia.  Usually I have to pay extra for that.

Comment: Philadelphia is one of my favorite places ever, and I am totally behind this.

Answer (score 5):

## London

For British and West-European Arqanauts (and excessively rich Arqanauts from elsewhere!). It's got good transport links, and good beer. I know this goes against the 'stay away from large cities' instruction, but if those of us who live around Europe want to meet somewhere we can actually get to, it's going to have to be somewhere sensible!

*If London is possible for you, **leave a comment** so we can see who would be able to attend vs. any other European locations people suggest.*

Comment: As far as I can see London and Wrocław are the 2 cheapest places for me to fly to.

Comment: Depends a lot on the dates

Comment: Oh my god... you can't seriously say that London has good beer... well not locally anyway.

Comment: @Lyrion Depends where you go...

Comment: I'd love to meet up with fellow enlightened gamers in London. Seems like the perfect setup for a memorable event...

Answer (score 5):

## Toronto

Or a suburb nearby like Mississauga or something if that's cheaper.

There is a huge cluster of dots in the northeast of North America, kind of centered around New York State. There is no one who actually lives in central New York State, however, to figure out accommodations, so Toronto is really the next closest where nearby users can provide their local insight to help with the event.

Plus Toronto is just a cool place. I want to go there again.

Comment: I knew someone was going to suggest this.  Heck, I'm one of the farthest from this one, and I'm going to try to make it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should please feel free to offer a better suggestion.

Comment: @StrixVaria Mayhaps they just dislike Canadians?

Comment: Toronto is reasonably close for me, as is Mr. or Miss Issauga

Comment: I need an excuse to go visit my sister between now and Christmas or so.  This might as well be it.

Comment: If Toronto works for people, I can help plan, as I am like an hour away :D

Comment: @RavenDreamer Us Canadians are a shifty bunch.

Comment: Although the time would heavily influence whether or not I could go, Toronto would be doable for me. Plus, I'd love to visit Toronto, because I've never been there.

Comment: My family is from Central NY actually.

Comment: *sigh* I guess this would be a good excuse to finally get my passport.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Time to pop your T.O. cherry.

Answer (score 5):

## Boston

PAX East is April 6-8 (yes still a while away though)

I've noticed that a lot of people live along the NE Railway line.  I take Amtrak quite often down to DC and I have to highly recommend this mode of travel.  Often its cheaper than air and way more convenient (you can get into the station 15 min ahead of time rather than 2 hours) and you won't have to be groped by the TSA to ride the train.

Also, the Boston Metro has connecting service from the Amtrak station to everywhere downtown so there's no need for rental cars, etc.

The drawback is that hotels may be a bit more expensive during this time, and there's always the risk of bad weather (snow in April is pretty rare though).

Comment: Snow?  Pfft, that's not bad weather.  *Blizzards* in -40 is bad weather.

Comment: I would be willing to do a Boston meet-up, especially if I get PAX-E tickets.  For me, personally, a meet-up would have to take place in Boston, Montreal, Toronto, or Halifax (although to be honest, just me and Wipqozn in a pub downtown would be kinda boring).

Comment: I know I'm not a super active Arqanaut, but I'm planning on going to PAXE and would love to meet up at the con or nearby.

Answer (score 0):

## Seattle

It's probably far too late for this, but Seattle!  It's on the west coast, which is the best coast.  Also, I live here.  Soo, Seattle!